# Pandas/Python: Store values of columns into list based on value in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following problem:

I want to store the values of the four different columns (Age_1 - Age_4) within a dataframe into a list, which is depending on the first column 'Year'.

| Year | Age_1 | Age_2 | Age_3 | Age_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | 18 | 20 | 25 | 56 |
| 2000 | 17 | 32 | 24 | 41 |
| 2001 | 20 | 26 | 24 | 39 |

...

So basically I want a list that then just contains all the ages that there is in the dataset for every year e.g. The first list would be list_2000 = [18,20,25,56,17,32,24,41...], the second would then be list_2001 = [20,26,24,39...]

Actually I assume that this should be easy to do, but my attempts weren't successful yet. So any help is apprechiated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, use the underlying numpy array and `groupby`, then flatten the data with `ravel` and transform to list with `tolist`:

```
dic = (
 df.set_index('Year').groupby(level='Year')
   .apply(lambda d: d.to_numpy().ravel().tolist())
   .to_dict()
)
```

output:

```
{2000: [18, 20, 25, 56, 17, 32, 24, 41], 2001: [20, 26, 24, 39]}
```

Comment: I do now have another question: I can't figure out how to boxplot these values that are stored inside this dictionary? So ideally I could plot 1 boxplot for every key = year.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC,

```
df.melt('Year',
        value_vars=['Age_1', 'Age_2', 'Age_3', 'Age_4'])\
.groupby('Year')['value'].agg(list).to_dict()
```